# angularjs-routing linked divs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

My routing is working fine but for some reason when I tried to add a carousel instead of just the images the entire page slides in from the side.

I am not sure if my structuring is correct or if I am missing something?

**app.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('Main', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'Main.Controller'])

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/app', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'appCtrl'
    }).when('/Home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/Home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/Portfolio', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/Portfolio.html',
        controller: 'PortfolioCtrl'
    }).when('/Contact', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/Contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/Home"
    });

})
```

**HomePage**

```
<header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/Headers.jpg" />" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/Headers.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ...
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- class="page {{ pageClass }}"-->
  <!-- Section One -->
<section class="One">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-left">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2 class="Section-title">About</h2>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-8 text-left border">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check for href of carousel which may interfere with your routing

href="#carousel-example-generic"

refer [Bootstrap carousel not working with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907843/bootstrap-carousel-not-working-with-angularjs)

[Angular routing with bootstrap carousel issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076069/angular-routing-with-bootstrap-carousel-issue)